# Filtering multiple columns with str_detect

Tags: r

I'm utilizing the function `str_detect` from tidyverse to filter out rows of a data frame that match the start of any string from a list.  Currently, utilizing `|` statement when filtering between each column within my `filter` statement.  Is there any way to utilize `str_detect` across multiple columns without using or statements?  The code I'm currently using below works, but does not scale.

```
Dataframe <- data.frame("names" = c('John','Jill','Joe','Mark'), "Jobs" = c('Mailman','Jockey','Jobhunter',"Nojob"))

Filter_list <- c('Jo')

Dataframe %>% filter(str_detect(names, paste0("^(", paste(Filter_list, collapse = "|"), ")")) |
                     str_detect(Jobs, paste0("^(", paste(Filter_list, collapse = "|"), ")"))

  names      Jobs
1  John   Mailman
2  Jill    Jockey
3   Joe Jobhunter)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `filter_at`:

```
Dataframe %>% filter_at(.vars = vars(names, Jobs),
                    .vars_predicate = any_vars(str_detect(. , paste0("^(", paste(Filter_list, collapse = "|"), ")"))))
```

If you want to apply the filter to all varaibles then you can use `filter_all`

Answer (score 0):

I would convert this to long data first and then use `str_detect()`

```
DF <- Dataframe %>% mutate(ID = row_number())
Index <- DF %>% gather(key, value, -ID) %>% filter(str_detect(value, Filter_list))
DF %>% filter(ID %in% unique(Index$ID))
```