# Reverse filtering multiple columns with str_detect

Tags: r

I came across this stack overflow QA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479243/11799491

and I want to know how to select all rows that do not match the string detect from the accepted answer. I tried using a ! in front of str_detect and it did not work.

```
Dataframe %>% filter_at(.vars = vars(names, Jobs),
                    .vars_predicate = any_vars(!str_detect(. , paste0("^(", paste(Filter_list, collapse = "|"), ")"))))
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new version of `dplyr` i.e. `1.0.4`, we can use `if_any` within `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Dataframe %>% 
  filter(!if_any(c(names, Jobs),
     ~ str_detect(., str_c("^(", str_c(Filter_list, collapse="|"), ")"))))
#    names  Jobs
#1  Mark Nojob
```

The "Nojob" is not matched because we are checking whether the string starts (`^`) with "Jo" (also the case is different)

---

In the older version, we can negate (`!`) with `all_vars`

```
Dataframe %>%
   filter_at(.vars = vars(names, Jobs),
                   .vars_predicate = all_vars(!str_detect(. , paste0("^(", paste(Filter_list, collapse = "|"), ")"))))
#   names  Jobs
#1  Mark Nojob
```

---

The reason why `any_vars` with `!` didn't work is that it is looking for any column that doesn't have a match for the string.  So, if one of the column row doesn't have that match while the other have it, then it returns that row.  Whereas with `all_vars` and negate, it will only return that row, when all those columns specified in `vars` are not matching

In the previous version, we cannot negate (`!`) in front of `any_vars` whereas it is not the case with `if_any` as `if_any` is returning a logical vector to be passed directly to `filter` whereas `any_vars` is doing it indirectly to `filter_at`

NOTE: The function wrapper that corresponds to `all_vars` is `if_all` in the current version

#### data

```
Dataframe <- data.frame("names" = c('John','Jill','Joe','Mark'), "Jobs" = c('Mailman','Jockey','Jobhunter',"Nojob"))

Filter_list <- c('Jo')
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your explanations!